# codeigniter and mysql: where statement only works on some cases

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to compare a variable in my database named bed_no which is in varchar to the input of the user. when the user inputs only numbers it doesn't work. but when the user inputs numbers and letters it works. for example when the user inputs 11111 as bed_no it doesn't work but when the user inputs a11111 the where statement works.

this is my model in codeigniter:

```
             public function add_doubledeck(){
                     $price = $this->input->post('price');
                     $bed_no = $this->input->post('bed_no');

                     $position = $this->input->post('position');


                     $data = array(

                     'price' => $price,
                     'position' => $position
                      );



                      $this->db->where('bed_no', $bed_no );

                      if($this->db->update('beds', $data)){
                      echo "Successfully inserted bed!";
                        } 
                      else{
                         echo "Could not process adding bed!";
                           }
                      }
```

Comment: Is that a model or a controller? You sholdnt do $this->input->post into a model.

Can you do a var_dump of $bed_no for each case? (when it works and when it doesnt)

Comment: This is a model. But it goes through the controller. So i think it should work. But the where clause is the only one that doesn't work.

Comment: change $bed_no = $this->input->post('bed_no'); to $bed_no = (string) $this->input->post('bed_no'); and try.

Comment: oh.. correction... the code doesn't work if the first digit is a number but if the first digit is a letter it works.

Comment: when i changed it to $bed_no = (string) $this->input->post('bed_no'); it doesn't work at all anymore.

Comment: If you do a var_dump maybe we can help you.You can enable profiler to check the last query. ($this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE)). Paste the queries here please

Comment: I don't quite understand the var_dump? Where do I put $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE); ? in model or controller?